# Can I remove the default namespace when creating raw Soap XML?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, xml-serialization

I'm trying to send a soap request to a WCF service. I am building the soap request using the System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage() method.

I haven't gotten super deep into building the body, but here is what I have...

```
Message msg = Message.CreateMessage( MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10, "MethodName" );
msg.Headers.MessageId = new UniqueId( Guid.NewGuid().ToString() );
msg.Headers.Add( Message.CreateHeader( "Security", "",
    new Security()
    {
        TimeStamp = new TimeStampType() {
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            Expires = Created.AddDays( 1 )
        },
        UsernameToken = new UsernameToken() {
            Username = "stackoverflow",
            Password = new Password() {
                Type = "hashed",
                Value = "Password"
            }
        }
     } ) ) );

string s = msg.ToString();
```

When I run this, I get the following output. I'm using the Visual Studio XML Visualizer btw.

```
<s:Envelope>
    <s:Header>
        <Action>MethodName</Action>
        <MessageID>GUIDVALUE</MessageID>
        <Security>
            <Timestamp xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1">
               .....
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body />
</s:Envelope>
```

My question is, can I remove xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1" from the xml? It shows up in Timestamp and in UsernameToken.

Thanks

Comment: I had this problem too when first starting with WCF. I have to intercept the message before being sent out to tidy up the XML and transform the message. Unfortunately, I do not have access to this code otherwise I would share.

Comment: Take a look at IDispatchMessageInspector and IEndpointBehavior to modify the XML before it gets sent off.

Comment: so basically before it's sent off do an xsl transform? I was hoping I wouldn't need to do that :(

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I apologize. Hassan Boutougha's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set Namespace to empty in datacontract 
in a class that wrap your security and timestamp

```
  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
```

Comment: Security is the top level class

Comment: if it's your own class you have a TimeStamp property and it is before this property that you set datacontract with empty namespace to ensure that no namespace is displayed in soap

Comment: Yes, I created to test. We use a similar class in the service but we call the service differently. I was asked to send requests as soap xml and capture the returned xml to store in the db.